# Email a table from google sheets using app script - on click of a button

Tags: javascript, html, email, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am new to coding. This is my first query. Pardon me for mistakes.

I want to develop a simple code to take orders from customers. In the attached sheet - customers will select their products and a summary email should go to the customer's email id and the admin email id.

The email is getting sent with the correct subject line but the email body is incorrect.

The email body is - [object Object] - instead of the table with product details.

Below is the code. Please help. Thanks in advance.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1J4OHwN3MEJwqMhOMDWg2Mt6dgqjcVlGOc2bHOS5lmRY/edit#gid=1167211647

"Sheet - Order tab"

```
function orderemail() {
    var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
    var data = sh.getRange("A2:O38").getValues();
    //var htmltable =[];
    var TABLEFORMAT = 'cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2" dir="ltr" border="1" style="width:100%;table-layout:fixed;font-size:10pt;font-family:arial,sans,sans-serif;border-collapse:collapse;border:1px solid #ccc;font-weight:normal;color:black;background-color:white;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;font-style:normal;'
    var htmltable = '<table ' + TABLEFORMAT +' ">';
        for (row = 0; row<data.length; row++){
           htmltable += '<tr>';
           for (col = 0 ;col<data[row].length; col++){
              if (data[row][col] === "" || 0) {
                  htmltable += '<td>' + 'None' + '</td>';} 
              else if (row === 0)  {
                  htmltable += '<th>' + data[row][col] + '</th>';
              }
              else {htmltable += '<td>' + data[row][col] + '</td>';}
           }
        htmltable += '</tr>';
     }
     htmltable += '</table>';
     Logger.log(data);
     Logger.log(htmltable);

     var emailAddress = "chhedapriyank@gmail.com";
     var emailAddress2location = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Order tab").getRange("C25");
     var emailAddress2 = emailAddress2location.getValues();

     // Send Alert Email.
     var order = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Order tab").getRange("A2:K32");
     var message = order.getValues();
     var subject = 'New Order Alert';
     var subject2 = 'Order Summary';
     MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, {htmlBody: htmltable})
     MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress2, subject2, {htmlBody: htmltable})
     var reset = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Order tab").getRange("b3:j22");

     reset.clearContent();
     var reset2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Order tab").getRange("c25");
     reset2.clearContent();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I understand well the doc https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app

you don't have to pass an object as the *body* parameter of MailApp.sendEmail, but directly your text/html

so replace `{htmlBody: htmltable}` by `htmltable` in these lines :

```js
...
     MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, htmltable)
     MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress2, subject2, htmltable)
...
```

---

**edit**

you need to provide a text body before providing the options object,

> sendEmail(recipient, subject, body, options)

you were right about the syntax but you need a text before.
you can try this to test it :

```js
...
     MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, htmltable, {htmlBody: htmltable})
     MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress2, subject2, htmltable,{htmlBody: htmltable})
...
```

but I recommend you create a text version of your data and pass it as the text body if it works

Comment: I have 2 more queries. 

1. Now when i am getting the email all the cells which are blank have a value of "none" in the table which i get on email. How do i ensure that they blank cells show as blank in the table?

2. I want to put the email id of the customer in the subject line of the email. Can you help me with how should i define the var = subject in order to do that? I need to pick the email id entered in c24

Answer (score 0):

to answer your further questions (from comment)

1 if you don't want blank to be "None" you should remove this part

```js
    var htmltable = '<table ' + TABLEFORMAT +' ">';
        for (row = 0; row<data.length; row++){
           htmltable += '<tr>';
           for (col = 0 ;col<data[row].length; col++){
              //remove this part ------------
              //if (data[row][col] === "" || 0) {
              //    htmltable += '<td>' + 'None' + '</td>';} 
              //else --------------
              if (row === 0)  {
                  htmltable += '<th>' + data[row][col] + '</th>';
              }
              else {htmltable += '<td>' + data[row][col] + '</td>';}
           }
        htmltable += '</tr>';
     }
```

2 - try this

````js
...

     // Send Alert Email.
     var order = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Order tab").getRange("A2:K32");
     var message = order.getValues();
     //---------------------- this :
     var customerId = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
       .getSheetByName("Order tab").getRange("c24")
       .getValues()[0];
     var subject = 'New Order Alert - ' + customerId;
     var subject2 = 'Order Summary - ' + customerId;
...
```
````

Comment: thanks! all this is very helpful.

As a next step i wish to send the table only with the rows where there is a product selected. Currently it is sending all the 20 rows with blank cells even if only 2 products have been selected. Is that possible? if so can you please help with how to do it. thanks once again! very helpful!